# In asp.net framework 4.0, how to implement Stripe PaymentGateway without nuget?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments

I have a website implemented in asp.net framework 4.0, and now i need to implement stripe payment gateway to integrate. but because it is website i am not able to add stripe.net thorough nuget. so please provide way where nuget package is not included.

Comment: Why my reputation point is decreased? and why i got down vote for this post. is this question is not valid or you haven't any solution for this so you decreased my reputation point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We will be glad to help if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, Payment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use nuget, What you can do is:

1. Manually Download `stripe.net` package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/
   There is a download link on the right under the `info` panel
2. When you downloaded, you see something like `stripe.net.19.6.x.nuget`
   Simply rename it to `stripe.net.19.6.x.zip`
3. Unzip the package and you will be able to find the dll under `\lib\net45` folder

use that dll as library reference. You should be good to go

Comment: Its Really Works for me.